# TypeError: menu is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

I have this error that I can't find why it is not being called properly menu is a function yet it says it is not. error (TypeError: menu is not a function) I tried to move it before the HTML that calls it but that did not work.

```
<script>
    var dropdown = document.querySelector("nav .dropdown");
    var menu = document.querySelector("nav div .menu");

    function menu()
    {
        if(dropdown.style.display === "none")
        {
            dropdown.style.display = "grid";
        }
        else
        {
            dropdown.style.display = "none";
        }
    } </script>

<input class="button" type="button" onclick="location.href='Controller/logout.php';" value="logout" /> <nav>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="links">
            <a href="Home">Home</a>
            <a href="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
        </div>
        <i class="material-icons menu" onclick="menu()">menu</i>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="Home">Home</a>
        <a href="Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="Reviews">Reviews</a>
    </div> </nav>
```

Comment: add these script tags : <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

Comment: what uses jquery?

Comment: Did it worked?? also can you change the `menu()` to something like `menubtn`, since `menu` is a keyword and you're using it as `selector` in `onclick`, it may also be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

That probably returns an error, since the naming issues.
`Menu is not a function` because you first initialize it with `var` and then redefine it with `function`. 
Try renaming either of variables (or even remove the first one, since it's never used)

Answer (score 0):

it's not working because you declare "menu" as html class and JS function.
just rename your function at both place.

```
<i class="material-icons menu" onclick="menu()">menu</i>
```

to

```
<i class="material-icons menu" onclick="menuFunc()">menu</i>
```

also

```
function menu()
```

to

```
function menuFunc()
```